# Give the named function argument a default value if not specified

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, optional-parameters, named-function

I created a formula to sort positive values.

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A>0),1,1)
```

And turnd it to a [named function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534?hl=en) with this formula definition, and named it `SORT_POSITIVE`

```
=SORT(FILTER(range, range>0),sort_column,is_ascending)
```

To use it like this.

```
=SORT_POSITIVE(A2:A,1,1)
```

It retrieves the sort column from the sort function within, as well as whether the sort is ascending or not.

Is there a method to set the named function's *is_ascending* default value to "1" when I don't set it to "0" or "1" for desending or ascending in the named function?
To be used Like this

```
=SORT_POSITIVE(A2:A)
```

[Make a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/173RV2k-x1PiKXzObtQeTCmbYao0p7XJguhhjuglMsMc/copy) of the example sheet and the named function.

[image]

Recap: If the named function parameter is not supplied, use the default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [optional-arguments](/questions/tagged/optional-arguments) and it's a well known feature in major programming languages like [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [python](/questions/tagged/python). It is also available in built in functions. But unfortunately, it's not currently available in [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets).  Microsoft introduced `LAMBDA` a year back in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel). After some time, it also added [LAMBDA improvements](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/bc-p/2596818). To quote,

> LAMBDA now supports optional parameters. To make use of optional parameters, all you need to do is wrap the optional name in “[]”.

> For example:

> =LAMBDA(param1, [param2], IF(ISOMITTED(param2), param1, param2))

> This lambda will return the value of param1 if param2 is omitted and otherwise return the value of param2.

For feature parity with excel, I would expect Google to follow suit. But, currently, both `ISOMITTED` and `[]`(optional arguments) are not available.

Answer (score 1):

With a work-around you can get close to your desired solution, **in some cases**, by providing fallback values via IF(ISBLANK()) in your named function.

**This will only work if your name function has more than 1 argument** (otherwise Sheets will return an error).

Replace your variables, ex:

```
sort_column
```

With a check if they are blank, and a default value to return if they are blank:

```
IF(ISBLANK(sort_column),DEFAULT_VALUE,sort_column)
```

In this case the resulting function is:

```
=SORT(FILTER(range,range>0),IF(ISBLANK(sort_column),1,sort_column),IF(ISBLANK(is_ascending),1,is_ascending))
```

Use the function with:

```
=SORT_POSITIVE(A2:A,,)
```

I also use this for optional validation, error checks, etc. which can be enabled via arguments while prototyping.

[Copy the updated Sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1km3A4Z-ovQVUJAjYanREJHnx364dXUzxYx5dGSuH5rA/copy)